# Location of Google .NET SDK documentation for DV360 API? #google-api-dotnet-client

Tags: c#, .net, google-api-dotnet-client, dv360

Building out tooling to automate some things for our accounts in DV360, I installed the SDK via NuGet in VS2019 Pro.  Noticed that the link provided in the NuGet package description is broken.

Checking the main API list page, I don't see an entry for the DV360 API.

Not listed:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/

Link given in NuGet (returns a 404):
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/displayvideo/v1

Comment: "Link given in NuGet" - which NuGet package? it would really help if you could provide the one *working* link (i.e. the NuGet package) as well as the broken ones...

Answer (score 0):

DV360 don't have .NET specific code sample and examples yet. For Reporting front
you can refer their API Doc - https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/v1.1 which lists all resource and method available on DV360 Platform.

Resource and Methods are available in doc can access through - `Google.Apis.DoubleClickBidManager.v1_1.DoubleClickBidManagerService` class included in `Google.Apis.DoubleClickBidManager.v1_1` Nuget Package.

Example -
To Get Report and its Files - https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/v1.1/reports/listreports

```cs
public ListReportsResponse Get(long reportId)
{
    return DoubleClickBidManagerService.Reports.Listreports(reportId).Execute();
}
```

To Create Report - https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/v1.1/queries/createquery

```cs
public long Create(Query query)
{
    var createQueryRequest = DoubleClickBidManagerService.Queries.Createquery(query);
    var createQueryResponse = createQueryRequest.Execute();
    return createQueryResponse.QueryId ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Response Query Id is null.");
}
```

For Errors refer - https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/core_errors